# A formula for the infimum of two measures

Tags: measure-theory

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086275/infimum-of-two-measures) question the OP claims that given measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ on a measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$ we can define their infimum w.r.t. to the ordering of measures by:

$$(\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A) := \inf\{\mu_1(A\cap B)+\mu_2(A \cap B^c) : B\in \mathcal E\}$$

Unfornately I'm kind of weak in Analysis and I'm asking for a proof that this 
defines a measure.

(Not the actual question: Does this have anything to do with the concept of outer measure / Caratheodory's extension theorem? Because it looks somewhat similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property $(\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(\varnothing) = 0$ follows immediately from $\mu_1(\varnothing) = \mu_2(\varnothing) = 0$.

It remains to show the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2$ on $\mathcal{E}$. Thus let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a disjoint sequence in $\mathcal{E}$ and

$$A = \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty A_n.$$

For every $B\in \mathcal{E}$ we have

\begin{align}
\mu_1(A \cap B) + \mu_2(A \cap B^c) &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mu_1(A_n \cap B) + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mu_2(A_n \cap B^c) \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \bigl(\mu_1(A_n \cap B) + \mu_2(A \cap B^c)\bigr) \\
&\geqslant \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n),
\end{align}

and thus, taking the infimum over all $B$ on the left, we have the $\sigma$-superadditivity of $\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2$ on $\mathcal{E}$. Now if

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n) = +\infty,$$

the equality

$$(\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n)$$

follows trivially from the $\sigma$-superadditivity. So we need only look at the case

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n) < +\infty.$$

Then, for any given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose a sequence $(B_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{E}$ with $B_n \subset A_n$ and

$$\mu_1(A_n \cap B_n) + \mu_2(A_n \cap B_n^c) < (\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}}$$

for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let

$$B = \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty B_n.$$

Then

\begin{align}
\mu_1(A \cap B) + \mu_2(A \cap B^c) &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mu_1(A_n \cap B) + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mu_2(A_n\cap B^c) \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mu_1(A_n \cap B_n) + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mu_2(A_n \cap B_n^c) \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \bigl(\mu_1(A_n \cap B_n) + \mu_2(A_n \cap B_n^c)\bigr) \\
&< \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \biggl((\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}}\biggr) \\
&= \Biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n)\Biggr) + \varepsilon,
\end{align}

and hence

$$(\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A) \leqslant \Biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n)\Biggr) + \varepsilon$$

for every $\varepsilon > 0$, so the $\sigma$-subadditivity

$$(\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A) \leqslant \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2)(A_n)$$

also follows in the non-trivial case where the sum on the right is finite. Altogether, the $\sigma$-additivity is established.

Comment: Why can you choose $B_n \subset A_n$? And how do you get from $\mu_2(A_n \cap B^c)$ to $\mu_2(A_n \cap B_n^c)$?

Comment: @Dominik If we have an arbitrary $B \in \mathcal{E}$ and set $B_n = A_n \cap B$, then we have $A_n \cap B = A_n \cap (A_n \cap B) = A_n \cap B_n$ and $A_n \cap B^c = A_n \cap (A_n^c \cup B^c) = A_n \cap (A_n \cap B)^c = A_n \cap B_n^c$.